# What key technologies in today's world would not exist if flight was never discovered?

Tags: technology, alternate-history, flight, history

For an alternate world sci-fi novel, I'm trying to figure out which technologies they have.

I would prefer for flight not to exist. Would this interfere with things like computer technology? I believe this was discovered for diverent reasons. But did the discovery of flight, and the discoveries made because of that technology, make some component to discovering computers possible? And what other technologies would not be possible without flight being invented?

Comment: Are you saying space-flight is out too?

Comment: It depends on how they would be prevented from discovering flight. Aerodynamics are in pretty much everything transport related, and from them it's pretty easy to figure out flight. It would influence your entire transport system significantly.

Comment: I think the really big question that needs answering b4 anyone can reasonably have a go at this for you is how exactly are you expecting to prevent the 'discovery' of flight, are you including all methods of traveling through the air, because there is more than way to achieve 'flight', lighter than air & powered are the two broadest categories.

Comment: No flight probably means no propeller driven boats for a start, bit hard to explain how having that it wouldn't be developed into an airplane propeller, rockets & jet engines are also out, as are balloons, dirigibles & airships ~ though I can't think of any major crossovers between them it's ***very*** hard to imagine a world where computers are invented but none of the basic technologies involved in flight have been.

Comment: *"I would prefer for flight not to exist":* as in no insects, no birds, no bats? No balloons? You see, balloons are a direct application of buoyancy; if they have boats and chemistry just a liitle more advanced than the 17th century then they will have balloons. No rockets? Rockets are *medieval* technology. In Europe they had fireworks in the 1300s, in China one or two centuries earlier. Really, it is very hard to have modern-ish physics and chemistry and not have flying machines.

Comment: I think perhaps your only plausible way to 'prevent' flight technologies developing is to not have them 'not discovered' but to have them suppressed in some fashion, religious laws proscribing any attempt to 'reach the heavens', aliens popped by & dropped a bunch of orbital lasers around the planet that shoot down anything bigger than an albatross or above a particular height (or else left over from a world war & no one alive knows the security codes to switch them off), some ubiquitous aggressive arial fauna (big birds or something else) that attacks anything man made in the air etc.

Comment: ^ Suppressing flight rather than the knowledge needed for it makes a lot more sense to me.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. They're very helpful, I do think I'll need to adjust my thinking on this a bit. I'm amazed at the quickness and amount of reactions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to have to frame-challenge this idea.

Look around you and you see birds and insects flying.  There are creatures that glide.  It's hard to imagine any world where some sort of flying creature did not exist.  Once you see that and you're any form of creature inclined to ask questions like "how are they doing that ?" and "could I do that ?", you're going to reach an end-point where flight (as a science) is discovered.

Even if birds and other flying creatures did not exist (which the only way people aren't going to notice flying), the first time someone thinks about what happens when they throw something and it glides further than other non-aerodynamic objects, they're going to discover flight.

What about when you drop something like a feather or anything that doesn't fall like a rock ?  People are going to standing wondering why.  Again, people will work out the principles of flight.

Let's somehow have an undersea culture which never experiences birds or insects. Water is still a fluid.  How fish swim and maintain bouyancy and so on will translate eventually into flight, because eventually they're going to ask about what happens above the sea in the atmosphere.  They'll work out how to fly eventually.

Only creatures completely devoid of any curiosity would avoid this.  But they also won't develop any other science or engineering or probably even basic agriculture.

There's just no way to avoid learning about flight.

> Computers

Computers are just devices designed to automate task.  The most significant development that led to programmable computers was probably the [Jacquard Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacquard_machine).  Calculation aids like the abacus developed into more sophisticated machines.  None of this is flight related.  Something like these devices (and what they develop into) will inevitably be produced by any organized industrial system.

Comment: The scenario is unbelievable but a frame challenge still doesn't really belong in answers.

Comment: @Pelinore: A frame challenge absolutely belongs in answers.

Comment: @AlexP : Really? I'll have to check the tour out again then.

Comment: @Pelinore The policy for frame challenges has been debated in the WB Meta more than once I believe.  Here's [one example](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2951/it-wont-work-challenging-the-frame-of-a-question).  Basically we don't want to encourage arbitrary attacks on questions, but genuine attempts to explain why someone thinks a question is deeply flawed are reasonable.  We also need to give newish posters some idea of how to critique their own ideas before posting them on WB SE.

Comment: @StephenG : Cheers, the reasoning makes a lot of sense, often a lot easier to explain fundamental issues with the question with the space afforded by an answer.

Comment: @StephenG : Also helps keep excessive back & forth comments on an individual frame challenge off the question, two or three separate challenges under the question can run away very quickly making it very messy, putting it in a answer helps avoid that.